# caught segfault ... memory not mapped in R DBI query

Tags: r, postgresql, segmentation-fault, dbi

I get a segfault error whenever an error is returned from a DBI query (using RPostgreSQL). This happens on any error condition reported back from the request. [This error can also be generated by a misspelling in the dbConnect() call.]  I'm using MacOS 11.6.4.

Here is the information from a sample session:

R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

...

/Users/wms5f/Programming/R/R-libraries /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library
[R.app GUI 1.78 (8075) x86_64-apple-darwin17.0]

```
> lbry<-c("DBI", "RPostgreSQL")
> test <- suppressMessages(lapply(lbry, require, character.only=TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE))
> db_driver = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
> db_user = 'my_acct'
> db_pwd = "my_pwd"
> db_host = 'my_host'
> db_name = 'a_db_name'
> table = "a_table_name"
> db <- DBI::dbConnect(db_driver,user=db_user, password=db_pwd,dbname=db_name, host=db_host)
> sessionInfo()
```

R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] RPostgreSQL_0.7-3 DBI_1.1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0

```
> dbGetQuery(db, "select 1")

  ?column?
1        1
> 
> dbGetQuery(db, "select 1 2")

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xcdc68ae0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...)
 2: dbSendQuery(con, statement, ...)
 3: dbSendQuery(con, statement, ...)
 4: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 5: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call, nlines = 1L)        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        sm <- strsplit(conditionMessage(e), "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && isTRUE(getOption("show.error.messages"))) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
 8: try(dbSendQuery(con, statement, ...))
 9: postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...)
10: dbGetQuery(db, "select 1 2")
11: dbGetQuery(db, "select 1 2")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Comment: I did an experiment replacing the RPostgreSQL package with RPostgres. This no longer created the segfault error, but returned an appropriate error message. The problem appears to be with the RPostgreSQL package. The problem is apparently with the RPostgreSQL package.

Comment: Sounds like a repeat of [tomoakin/RPostgreSQL#120](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/issues/120), fixed with [9eba3f3](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/commit/9eba3f3a9d7a23f8fc5f47b0ac8280fa04a5d696), which is in version `0.7-4`, which is sadly not yet on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html) (still showing `0.7-3`). I suggest you can either stay with `RPostgres` (most things are a 1-for-1 swap, good thing) or compile/install the github version to confirm and continue using.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).